# How to completely stop a continuous rotation servo using pyfirmata

Tags: python, arduino, servo

I recently purchased four continuous rotation servo motors (FS90R). Using an Arduino Uno, Pycharm and pyfirmata, I wanted to test the various speed caps of the servo. I used this piece of code:

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino

board = Arduino('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201')

pin = board.get_pin('d:8:s')
pin.write(10)
```

which works; however, after uploading

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino

board = Arduino('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201')

pin = board.get_pin('d:8:s')
pin.write(0)
```

The servo would stop for a little bit, and then continue spinning as if nothing happened. I tried putting a while True: loop, but it did not work.
I would like to know how to completely stop the servo for an indefinite amount of time. All answers are appreciated.

Comment: The continuous servos are usually stoped around 90° (middle) and 0 is full speed anticlockwise, 180 full speed clockwise rotation.

Comment: And if you meant "The servo stops for few seconds start of the script", that will be Arduino auto-reset when script connects to usb-seral and the arduino gets into the bootloader for few seconds

Comment: @KIIV Alright, thank you.